# Does Prometheus' "container_fs_usage_bytes" contain PVCs?

Tags: prometheus

I want to measure the local volume usage of POD excluding PVC.
Does the "container_fs_usage_bytes" query include PVC usage?

Also, is there any query to know the maximum value of the local volume?

Comment: By `local`, do you mean `inmem` or `hostPath` volume?